# CSS Flexbox and javascript DIV sizing

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm converting a website from a fixed width design to Flexbox layout. The majority of the site I'm able to get working well. However, there is a page where I need to create a series of DIVS in javascript as part of an AJAX routine - the content is dynamically loaded.

The problem I have is that the DIVS created in the javascript aren't working properly as Flexbox parents. They do wrap correctly and I can add padding/styles etc through the CSS but I can't get the sizing of them to work. I need two boxes on each line and have set these to be 40% but it completely ignores this from the CSS and only populates the boxes to the width of the content it puts in them plus any padding I've specified in the CSS.

The Flexbox CSS:

```
.contentholder {
    margin:0;      
      padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
     background:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px dotted #ed0bea;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:left;        
    -webkit-display: box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;  
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content:space-between;
    -moz-justify-content:space-between;
    -ms-justify-content:space-between;
    justify-content:space-between;  
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;} 

  .contentholder {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 40%;
        -webkit-flex: 1 1 40%;
        -moz-flex: 1 1 40%;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 40%;
        flex: 1 1 40%;}
```

Here is an example of a section of the javascript I use to create the DIVS and content:

```
var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById('placeholderbox');
        //CREATE CONTENT HOLDER BOX
        var divRHolder = document.createElement('div');
        divRHolder.className = "contentholder";
        placeholderDiv.appendChild(divRHolder);
        //CREATE RESULT INFO DIV
        var divRInfo = document.createElement('div');
        divRInfo.className = "resultinfo";
        divRInfo.innerHTML = 'Some text in here';
        divRHolder.appendChild(divRInfo);
```

If anyone can give me any tips it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:
In terms of the html, I have a Flexbox wrapper which contains the header, nav bar, content and footer etc. Everything displays correctly except this content on this page.

In the content section I have place holder divs for my results. This is linked to the javascript with the DIV id:

```
<div id="placeholderbox"></div>
    <div id="placeholderboxa"></div>    
<div id="placeholderboxb"></div> etc etc etc
```

Comment: I think it can be helpful to provide your HTML code to go along your CSS and JS

Comment: Flexbox are complicated, but you should try this to understand how to use them http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: Thanks @Jaay have added a summary.

Comment: In your CSS, should the first slector not be `#placeholderbox`?

Comment: @Shaggy I use <div id="placeholderbox"></div> as not every box always has content and I only want ones with content to be displayed. This DIV is linked to the javascript with the getElementById and then only goes on to create a visible div on the page when valid content is returned from the server (AJAX).